# Finding substring inside string with any order of characters of substring in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, substring, time-complexity

Suppose I have a string "abcdpqrs",
now "dcb" can be counted as a substring of above string as the characters are together.
Also "pdq" is a part of above string. But "bcpq" is not. I hope you got what I want.
Is there any efficient way to do this.
All I can think is taking help of hash to do this. But it is taking long time even in O(n) program as backtracking is required in many cases. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: ... [regex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/)?

Comment: Do you mean using "regex" library of C. Haven't tried that. Any help in how to use it?

Comment: Regexes are a long and complicated subject that entire books are written about. But [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) is a good language-agnostic tutorial set on the general concept. Are you on C++ 11? If not, to get Regex's in C++ you'll need to use a third-party library like [``boost::regex``](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: Even regex for this will be complicated. Any other way to optimize the naive scanning algorithm?

Comment: Do you have one needle and one haystack, or do you search for many needles in the same haystack>

Comment: Also, can the same character occur multiple times in either needle or haystack?

Comment: one needle one haystack. But chars can be multiple in both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an O(n * alphabet size) solution:

Let's maintain an array count[a] = how many times the character a was in the current window [pos; pos + lenght of substring - 1]. It can be recomputed in O(1) time when the window is moved by 1 to the right(count[s[pos]]--, count[s[pos + substring lenght]]++, pos++). Now all we need is to check for each pos that count array is the same as count array for the substring(it can be computed only once).

It can actually be improved to O(n + alphabet size):

Instead of comparing count arrays in a naive way, we can maintain the number diff = number of characters that do not have the same count value as in a substring for the current window. The key observation is that diff changes in obvious way we apply count[c]-- or count[c]++ (it either gets incremented, decremented or stays the same depending on only count[c] value). Two count arrays are the same if and only if diff is zero for current pos.

Comment: Yup... I have a better solution for the case when repetition isn't allowed, but I think this is optimal when repetition is allowed.

Comment: I think 26*n is the only optimal soln then to this?

Comment: not exactly 26, this solution will be a little tricky since you can have other chars in the string... are you planning only lowercase?

Comment: yes i mean lets say we just consider lower case(a-z)

Comment: I came up with O(n + aplhabet size solution) and I have edited my answer.

Comment: You could maintain only differences (i.e. before starting, set `count[c] = -count_needle[c]` )

Comment: This is a common problem where you'd use a suffix trie. see my answer. O(m) search possible here (m being length if inputstring).

Comment: Your Big O is wrong. The number of comparisons required is much more than this.

Comment: Indeed, I misunderstood something at first. I think this is a good way. However, if n is very large, and m (search string) is small, my suggestion may have an advantage in some cases. But I agree this is the generally best answer.

Comment: I've edited my answer (suggestion rather) to state it may fit certain cases better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex (i.e boost or Qt) for this. Alternately you an use this simple approach. You know the length k of the string `s` to be searched in string `str`. So take each k consecutive characters from `str` and check if any of these characters is present in `s`.

Starting point ( a naive implementation to make further optimizations):

```
#include <iostream>

/* pos position where to extract probable string from str
*  s string set with possible repetitions being searched in str
*  str original string
*/
bool find_in_string( int pos, std::string s, std::string str)
{
    std::string str_s = str.substr( pos, s.length());
    int s_pos = 0;

    while( !s.empty())
    {
        std::size_t found = str_s.find( s[0]);
        if ( found!=std::string::npos)
        {
            s.erase( 0, 1);
            str_s.erase( found, 1);
        } else return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

bool find_in_string( std::string s, std::string str)
{
    bool found = false;
    int pos = 0;    
    while( !found && pos < str.length() - s.length() + 1)
    {
        found = find_in_string( pos++, s, str);
    }

    return found;
}
```

Usage:

```
int main() {

    std::string s1 = "abcdpqrs";
    std::string s2 = "adcbpqrs";
    std::string searched = "dcb";
    std::string searched2 = "pdq";
    std::string searched3 = "bcpq";
    std::cout << find_in_string( searched, s1);
    std::cout << find_in_string( searched, s2);
    std::cout << find_in_string( searched2, s1);
    std::cout << find_in_string( searched3, s1);

    return 0;
}
```

prints: 1110

http://ideone.com/WrSMeV

Comment: There is a caveat in your idea (maybe?)... Since set only get each element once, what happens if he try to search "aaa" inside "abc"?

Comment: it is domain range error but we can handle this easily

Comment: I'm not criticising, I really liked you idea, very smart... but needs an adaptation if repetitions are allowed

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have the string "axcdlef" and wants to search "opde":

```
bool compare (string s1, string s2)
{
  // sort both here
  // return if they are equal when sorted;
}
```

you would need to call this function for this example with the following substrings of size 4(same as length as "opde"):

"axcd" 
"xcdl"
"cdle"
"dlef"

```
  bool exist = false;

  for (/*every split that has the same size as the search */)
      exist = exist || compare(currentsplit, search);
```

Comment: how about checking "dde" in "adedem"?

Comment: @rocker: That's a match: `a(ded)em`

Comment: when you search the second time(second string of len 3), you will send "ded" and "dde" to the function, there they will be sorted and it will return true

Comment: oh okay I thought you are sliding the window by substring size. yup that will work. But wont be optimized as sorting will be required

Comment: well, the other one you will have to do other stuff with the array... I was writing a solution with map and then saw this guy with sorting and stopped, I'll write the map one I thought

Answer (score 0):

To use an array for this you are going to need some extra code to map where each character goes in there... Unless you know you are only using 'a' - 'z' or something similar that you can simply subtract from 'a' to get the position.

```
bool compare(string s1, string s2)
{
   int v1[SIZE_OF_ALFABECT];
   int v2[SIZE_OF_ALFABECT];
   int count = 0;
   map<char, int> mymap;

  // here is just pseudocode
   foreach letter in s1:
      if map doesnt contain this letter already:
           mymap[letter] = count++;

 // repeat the same foreach in s2

 /* You can break and return false here if you try to add new char into map, 
  that means that the second string has a different character already... */

 // count will now have the number of distinct chars that you have in both strs

 // you will need to check only 'count' positions in the vectors

 for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    v1[i] = v2[i] = 0;

 //another pseudocode
   foreach letter in s1:
      v1[mymap[leter]]++;
   foreach letter in s1:
      v2[mymap[leter]]++;

  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
      if(v1[i] != v2[i])
          return false;

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a O(m) best case, O(m!) worst case solution - m being the length of your search string:

Use a suffix-trie, e.g. a Ukkonnen Trie (there are some floating around, but I have no link at hand at the moment), and search for any permutation of the substring. Note that any lookup needs just O(1) for each chararacter of the string to search, regardless of the size of n.

However, while the size of n does not matter, this becomes inpractical for large m.

If however n is small enough anf one is willing to sacrifice lookup performance for index size, the suffix trie can store a string that contains all permutations of the original string.

Then the lookup will always be O(m).

I'd suggest to go with the accepted answer for the general case. However, here you have a suggestion that can perform (much) better for small substrings and large string.

Comment: How does it work for the following example: s = "abc" substring to search for = "cab"?

Comment: It doesn't work for this example. But your example is wrong. The OP clearly states that the characters are "together".

Comment: No. He states that the order of characters doesn't matter(that is, if any permutation of a substring to search is a substring in a traditional meaning, it matches).

Comment: Then use the permutation of that string to search. Checking the existence of a character after a given one is always O(1). So search performance would be O(m!) in the wirst case - if all permutations need be checked before a corresponding natch is found. And O(m) in best case, when the substring has an exact match. Or construct a suffix trie for all possible string permutations, if the string is not too large. Then you'd stick with O(m)